# Firebase Android - Message sending failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android development. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJ9OsJ6mzFE&index=4&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjxP_CHAhjXQN3zrcEhluF_) to enable push notification using Firebase. Sending a notification to my emulator using FCM Registration token message fails and I'm not sure why.

In the log it says FirebaseAuth is not linked (provided in the code snippet below).

```
04-23 12:09:23.001 2852-2852/com.example.bachao.bachaoapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
04-23 12:09:23.041 2852-2852/com.example.bachao.bachaoapp W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10012
04-23 12:09:23.053 2852-2852/com.example.bachao.bachaoapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.

04-23 12:09:54.324 2852-2875/com.example.bachao.bachaoapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-23 12:09:54.581 2852-2880/com.example.bachao.bachaoapp W/InstanceID/Rpc: No response android.os.ConditionVariable@d85606d
04-23 12:09:54.585 2852-2880/com.example.bachao.bachaoapp D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: TIMEOUT, retry in 10s
04-23 12:10:28.491 2852-3331/com.example.bachao.bachaoapp D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, retry in 20s
```

Could someone help me out in resolving this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Deby. Could you post the actual code you have at the moment? Also, could you elaborate on what the concern is? You mentioned that the token message is failing but the logs point out Firebase Auth? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps Below:-

```
1) set your emulator target to Google API 
2) add google account to your emulator:
setting->account&sync-> Add account
```